# Store split values from user response in C#

Tags: c#, split, user-input

I'm trying to create a grade calculator but I'm completely unsure how to compile the code to do so.

So far I've got the ability to split a user's response, but now I need to know how to take those splits and use them as separate values in order to create an average. I'm completely clueless how to achieve this and I've been searching for 2 days now on the internet with no luck.

```
Console.WriteLine ("User response seperated by commas goes here.");
string response = Console.ReadLine ();
Char delimiter = ',';
string[] splitResponses = response.Split (delimiter);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I need to know how to take those splits and use them as separate
>   values in order to create an average.

Not sure what you mean by ***take those splits and use them as separate
 values***, result is an array you could elements using index like `splitResponseses[0]`

To calculate the average you need to convert them to `ints` (or respective types), and calculate average.

```
string[] splitResponses = response.Split (delimiter);     // Split string

int sum=0; 
foreach(string s in splitResponses)
{
    var valueInt = int.Parse(s); // convert string to an int.

    sum+= valueInt;   
}   

double average = (double)sum/splitResponses.Length;
```

Another simple solution using `Linq` extensions.

```
int[] splitResponses = response.Split (delimiter)     // Split string
                               .Select(int.Parse)     // Convert To int value; 
                               .ToArray();
```

Now you could calculate average using

```
splitResponses.Average();   // Average
splitResponses.Sum();       // Sum
```

Comment: I don't quite follow, I'm fairly new to C# and I've only learned basic C# in university so far, the reason I'm trying to figure these things out is because soon I'm starting an Advanced C# course and I don't wanna be lost. This returned errors:

`Console.WriteLine ("User response seperated by commas goes here.");
   string response = Console.ReadLine ();
   Char delimiter = ',';
   int[] splitResponses = response.Split (delimiter);
   int[] splitResponses = response.Select (int.Parse);
   int[] splitResponses = response.ToArray();
   Console.WriteLine(splitResponses.Average());`

Comment: @Kankuro Check updated answer, I provided simple looping solution. Main catch here is converting to int, since `split` function returns an array of strings, you need to convert them to `int` first and then sum.

Comment: I don't get the Linq solution. What are you meaning to say when you put .Select and .ToArray on a new line?

Comment: `Linq` may be an advanced concept for beginners, I would suggest ignore `Linq` solution for now and try getting all basics, once you familiar with basics try reading and understanding [Linq](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/mt693024.aspx)

Comment: Okay, the other solution you provided threw an error saying "Use of unassigned local variable 'sum'" within the foreach loop.

Comment: We need to provide default value to `sum` variable, check now.

Comment: Okay, that worked as needed, but how would I build it to allow a while loop to validate that the user input integers and not letters or any other characters except commas?

Comment: That's new question altogether, I would suggest post new question. If we extend this answer it may confuse people reaching this post with the similar problem. Hope you understand.